# Installing Cobbler on Ubuntu 15.10 seems to break apache, how can I fix this?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, mod-python, ubuntu-15.10, cobbler

I am trying to install Cobbler on a brand new Ubuntu 15.10 virtual box but it is not working. When I run the `apt-get install cobbler cobbler-web` it seems to break apache completely to the point I can't get it working again.

I see this in the apache error log:

`[wsgi:crit] [pid 8112:tid 140273573488512] mod_wsgi (pid=8112): The mod_python module can not be used on conjunction with mod_wsgi 4.0+. Remove the mod_python module from the Apache configuration.`

and this in the `auth.log`:

`polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:8081:54865 (system bus name :1.24, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)`

I have tried removing the `mod_python` and `wsgi` modules but apache still doesn't start up. And I think Cobbler uses them anyways, so I kind of need them.

I have also tried disabling polkitd. I don't find any clues when searching for that weird error message.

I was able to install Cobbler on Ubuntu 14.04 pretty easily and apache works fine.

Here is the basic chain of install commands I used:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install isc-dhcp-server
apt-get install bind9 bind9utils bind9-doc
apt-get install cobbler cobbler-web debmirror mkisofs
```

Comment: FYI I ended up reverting to an older version of Ubuntu and it works fine.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: As of now, is there any other solution? Apart from changing Ubuntu version.
I am facing this issue in 16.04 too.

Comment: Try to download mod_wsgi (version 3.5 ) from https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases?after=4.2.0.|  Build using make and see.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the module by typing `sudo a2dismod python`

You should then see this:

> Module python disabled. To activate the new configuration, you need to
>   run:   service apache2 restart

So type `sudo service apache2 restart`.

If that doesn't fix it, check the error log for more information by typing
`cat /var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: I am using  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. This solution works for me.